# Solr CSV import that has a field with a non standard date format

Tags: solr, lucene, dataimporthandler

I am trying to import several .csv files that contain a few fields with a date format of "yyyyMMdd".  I quickly found that the DataImportHandler does not easily support csv files.  In the DataImportHandler, it is possible to use the LineEntityProcessor and then a RegexTransformer, but that is pretty messy.  The next method I tried was to post the file to the CSVRequestHandler, but I have not found a way to specify what SimpleDateFormat to use to parse the field.  I have been searching for a way around this problem, but I think I am doomed to either a pre-processing step, or mucking with the RegexTransformer.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:  I should add that I am on Solr 3.5.

Comment: Is this a one-time thing or is it something that needs to be automated?

Comment: This is a one time thing for these files, but I assume that as I begin to work with other sets of csv files, I will be running into the same problem.

Comment: I haven't used the CSVRequestHandler - I suggest a simple preprocessing step. Use Python to read in the CSV files and spit out XML, then run post.jar on the output files. IMO that's simpler and more robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or. to stay within solr. index it in a string field. and using an UpdateProcessor copy it to a date field in the right format. preety easy

Comment: I had a similar idea idea and spent some time yesterday looking for an example.  My thought was to use <copyField>, but the only attributes I could find were source and dest.  Today I will look into using an UpdateProessor.

Comment: This works great.  Should I be using a single UpdateRequestProcessor for all fields I want to work on in a record, or would it perform better if I define multiple (if even possible).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the [DateFormatTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#DateFormatTransformer)?

Comment: As far as I know, the DateFormatTransformer is only for DIH.  At the time of the writing of this question, DIH did not cleanly support .csv files.  The solution was to us an UpdateProcessor.